# Bounties of more than 200 points

Tags: discussion, bounty

If the daily limit for earned points is 200, what happens when your answer is selected as the correct one and the bounty on that question is for more than 200 points?

[See this question as an example](https://superuser.com/questions/342759/can-somebody-explain-about-wi-fi-device-manager-settings-and-power-settings-in-wi). The OP is asking for a significantly detailed answer, and it's probably right that he's salted the pot with this very large bounty. But will the person who gets the answer correct only get 200 of those points (or less depending on how many questions he got right that day)?

Comment: *salted* the pot? He'd have to offer -200 Rep then :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term you're looking for is `reputation cap` or rep cap for short.

No, bounties do not count towards the daily rep cap on any Stack Exchange sites.  Nor do accepted answers (the +15 rep from getting one of your answers marked as accepted).

Similar question on Meta Stack Overflow:

> [How do bounties affect the rep cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61010/how-do-bounties-affect-the-rep-cap)